# How did Maul get off of Naboo?

Tags: star-wars, sith, darth-maul

I was re-watching the *Star Wars The Clone Wars* Episodes about Darth Maul and Savage Opress and I realized that it was never explained how Maul actually got off of Naboo.
I am not asking how he survived that can probably be guessed easily enough seeing as the force can probably be used by the writers to do basically anything they want it to.
But I'm wondering how he got out if that huge pit and got off of Naboo. A task like that would be hard enough as is but it must be nearly impossible when he is cut in half.
So how did he get off of Naboo and onto that junkyard planet?
(Automatic up vote if you add the name of that junkyard planet in the answer)

Comment: I edited the question to show how it isn't a dupe.

Comment: Did you read the answers? This is a dupe.

Comment: @TheMandolorian Just letting you know that we're saying this is a dupe based on the answers rather than what the question is asking 

Comment: I read the answers that question was asking how he survived I am asking how he got off the planet

Comment: @N_Soong I have read the answers and they did not answer my question

Comment: @TheMandolorian The answer says "The Sith Lord was then dumped into a container, which was taken to Lotho Mino" - [Lotho Mino](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lotho_Minor) is a planet, hence it *does* describe how he got off Naboo

Comment: DVK explains it twice in his answer. `" He went down the reactor shaft and landed in water. The Sith Lord was then dumped into a container, which was taken to Lotho Minor. "` and `"... And on Page 26/27, they show him falling into some sort of a vat, and a ship picking up those vats and dropping them off on Lotho Minor:"`

Comment: I relize now that was wrong and did not read the answers carefully I apologize and will vote to close my question.

Comment: @TheMandolorian No worries!  We all make mistakes :D

Comment: But you don't have to delete your question just because it turned out to be a duplicate! Duplicates help to increase searchability, a dupe of a good question is often also a good question, and in fact it's [recommended](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7943/is-it-encouraged-to-delete-your-own-questions-if-they-have-possible-duplicates) that you *don't* delete it just for being a dupe.